# Change Text Of Submit Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the text on a HTML button when a action is invoked, But with no luck I seem to be missing something.

HTML:

```
<button name="Action" id="" name="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="SaveData">Update this text Page</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('SubmitButton').value = "New Text";
```

Comment: `id="name="SubmitButton"` ?

Comment: How do you call the function? Do you get errors?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Provide the ID of your button and how the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A button isn't like an input element so you need to use innerHTML

HTML

```
<button id="SubmitButton" type="submit">Update this text Page</button>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('SubmitButton').innerHTML = "New Text";
```

An input type submit on the other hand is an input and can have a value.

HTML

```
<input id="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="Update this text Page" />
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('SubmitButton').value = "New Text";
```

Comment: a buttton is a form element according to: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

Comment: @OmarGonzales amended to remove any incorrect semantics. To be honest it doesn't matter but it's best to be clear so I directly related it to an input as I use that in the demo

Answer (score 0):

Problems found:

- No ID assigned to your element
- To change a button's text, you need to use .innetHTML rather than .value
- The function was not being called.

Try this instead:

HTML:

```
<button id="SubmitButton" onclick="test(this)" type="submit">Update this text Page</button>
```

JS:

```
function test(e) {
    e.innerHTML = "New Text";
}
```